# calling modules from other modules. AttributeError: 'BoxCars' object has no attribute 'dice'

Tags: python

I have four modules that they call each other so I can play a box cars game (a game with dice).
each module has one class. the modules are die.py, pairOfDice.py, boxCars.py, and boxCarsStarter.py.
the boxCarStarter.py is the client, or it will run the actual game. The problem is when I try to run it it's giving me the attribute error. I'm still new to python so I don't know how to fix this problem, but I have a good background in java. Any help would be appreciated. I think the way I'm calling the other modules is the actual problem. The game is to roll a pair of dice and then according to what you get it will give you points, whoever reaches 150 points first win, but I don't think that the actual rules of the game matters.
p.s: in the actual source code the lines are indented correctly.

```
# this is the die.py class
from random import randint


class Die(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.side = 6
        self.face = 0

    def roll(self):
        face = randint(1, self.side+1)
        return face

    def get_face(self):
        return self.face



# This is the pairOfDice.py class
from assingments import die


class PairOfDice(object):
def __int__(self):
    self.die1 = die.Die()
    self.die2 = die.Die()

def get_die1(self):
    return self.die1.get_face()

def get_die2(self):
    return self.die2.get_face()

def roll(self):
    self.die1.roll()
    self.die2.roll()

def is_snake_eyes(self):
    flag = False
    if (self.get_die1() and self.get_die2()) == 1:
        flag = True
    return flag

def is_boxcars(self):
    flag = False
    if (self.get_die1() and self.get_die2()) == 6:
        flag = True
    return flag

def is_doubles(self):
    flag = False
    if (self.get_die1() == self.get_die2()) and not self.is_snake_eyes():
        flag = True
    return flag

def dice_sum(self):
    total = self.get_die1() + self.get_die2()

    return total



#this is the BoxCars.py class
import math
from assingments import pairOfDice


class BoxCars(object):
def __int__(self):
    self.dice = pairOfDice.PairOfDice()
    self.computer_score = 0
    self.human_score = 0
    self.name = ""

def player(self, s):
    self.name = s

def play_game(self):
    while True:
        self.computer_turn()
        self.between_turns()
        self.human_turn()
        self.between_turns()
        if (self.total_round_score() < 150) or self.human_score == self.computer_score:
            break

    if self.human_score > self.computer_score:
        print(f"{self.name}, congratulations! you beat the computer!")
    else:
        print(f"sorry, {self.name} you got beat by the computer")

def total_round_score(self):
    if self.human_score > self.computer_score:
        max_num = self.human_score
    else:
        max_num = self.computer_score

    return max_num


def between_turns(self):
    print(f"CURRENT GAME SCORE: COMPUTER: {self.computer_score}"
          f"   {self.name}: {self.human_score}\n")
    input("press ENTER to continue ...")


def snake_eyes(self, player_score):
    print('\t\t\tRolled snake eyes! All turn points will be doubled.')
    player_score += 2

    return player_score

def box_cars(self):
    print('\t\t\tRolled box cars! All points are gone now!')
    total_score = 0

    return total_score

def doubles(self):
    print('\t\t\tRolled double. . . lose all turn points.')
    round_score = 0

    return round_score

def default_dice(self, player_score):
    player_score += self.dice.dice_sum()

    return player_score

def computer_turn(self):
    computer = 0
    current_turn = 0
    count = 0
    stop = True

    print('Computer\'s turn')

    for i in range(5):
        if stop:
            self.dice.roll()
            print(f"\t\tRolled: {self.dice.get_die1()} and {self.dice.get_die2()}")

            if self.dice.is_snake_eyes():
                computer = self.snake_eyes(computer)
                count += 1

            elif self.dice.is_boxcars():
                computer = self.box_cars()
                self.computer_score = 0
                stop = False

            elif self.dice.is_doubles():
                computer = self.doubles()
                stop = False

            else:
                computer = self.default_dice(computer)

            if self.dice.is_doubles() or self.dice.is_boxcars():
                current_turn = 0

            else:
                current_turn += self.dice.dice_sum()

            print(f"\t\tCurrent score for this turn {current_turn}")

            if computer >= 20:
                stop = False

            computer *= math.pow(2, count)
            self.computer_score += computer

def human_turn(self):
    human = 0
    current_turn = 0
    count = 0
    stop = True
    question = 0

    print(self.name + "'s turn:")

    for i in range(5):
        if stop:
            self.dice.roll()
            print(f"\t\tRolled: {self.dice.get_die1()} and {self.dice.get_die2()}")

            if self.dice.is_snake_eyes():
                human = self.snake_eyes(human)
                count += 1

            elif self.dice.is_boxcars():
                human = self.box_cars()
                self.human_score = 0
                stop = False

            elif self.dice.is_doubles():
                human = self.doubles()
                stop = False

            else:
                human = self.default_dice(human)

            if self.dice.is_doubles() or self.dice.is_boxcars():
                current_turn = 0

            else:
                current_turn += self.dice.dice_sum()

            print(f"\t\tCurrent score for this turn: {current_turn}")

            if (question < 4) and stop:
                answer = input("Roll again> (y/n)")[0]
                if answer == 'n':
                    stop = False
                question += 1

            human += math.pow(2, count)
            self.human_score = human


# this is the boxCarsStarter.py class
from assingments import boxCars
box = boxCars.BoxCars()
print('welcome to BoxCars - The game of dice')
n = input("who is playing the game?")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    box.player(n)
    box.play_game()




# this is the error message when I run the boxCarsStarter.py.
welcome to BoxCars - The game of dice
who is playing the game?lauth
Computer's turn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Laith/PycharmProjects/New/assingments/boxCarsStarter.py", 
line 8, in <module>
    box.play_game()
  File "C:\Users\Laith\PycharmProjects\New\assingments\boxCars.py", line 17, in play_game
self.computer_turn()
```

File "C:\Users\Laith\PycharmProjects\New\assingments\boxCars.py", line 77, in computer_turn
self.dice.roll()
AttributeError: 'BoxCars' object has no attribute 'dice'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo `__int__`. Should be `__init__`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It actually fixed my problem. For some reason I thought that __init__   was a keyword and the IDE would show me that I have a syntax error. Thank you again.